# How to tell what has been destroyed by the destroy command in a kendo UI grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com) 2013.2.716 and [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) 2.0.3 and I am placing a [grid](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid) on my page, and my question is:

> Does anyone know how to tell what has been destroyed by the destroy command from the grid?

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>            
<div id="grid"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        var products = [];
        for(var i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
            products.push({
                ProductId: i,
                ProductName: "Product " + i
            });
        }    
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: products,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ProductId",
                        fields: {
                            ProductName: { type: "string" },
                        }
                    }
                },
                requestEnd: function (e) {
                    if (e.type === "destroy") {
                        alert("OK, so something got destroyed, but what??");
                    }
                }
            },
            editable: "inline",
            columns: [
                "ProductName",
                { command: "destroy", title: " ", width: "100px" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I found the `requestEnd` callback in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#events-requestEnd) but I am totally flummoxed as to know where the item that was destroyed would be.  I just need the ID of the item really so that I can update other parts of my page appropriately.

I am wondering if I need to capture it somehow beforehand.

Comment: Read this   http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Brett for pointing out the destroy property on the transport.  This code does the trick - allowing me to capture what was being destroyed (see the transport.destroy part):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>            
<div id="grid"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ProductId",
                        fields: {
                            ProductName: { type: "string" },
                        }
                    }
                },
                transport: {
                    read: function (options) {
                        var products = [];
                        for(var i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
                            products.push({
                                ProductId: i,
                                ProductName: "Product " + i
                            });
                        }    
                        options.success(products);
                    },
                    destroy: function (options) {                        
                        var data = $("#grid")
                            .data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
                        var products = [];
                        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            if (data[i].ProductId !== options.data.ProductId) {
                                products.push(data[i])
                            }
                        }
                        options.success(products);

                        alert("Woo hoo - the product with the ID: " 
                            + options.data.ProductId + " was destroyed!");
                    }
                }
            },
            editable: "inline",
            columns: [
                "ProductName",
                { command: "destroy", title: " ", width: "100px" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the `transport` object on your datasource. In your current configuration, does anything really get destroyed? Sure, the item may disappear from your grid, but I wonder if it's still there in the datasource. Maybe that's what you intended.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.destroy

If you're just looking for a way to get at the data that's being destroyed, hook into the `parameterMap()` function of the `transport` object. In there you can manipulate the object being deleted before the operation is executed.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap

Comment: +1 - thanks for the answer - it got me on the right track!  I used the destroy property on the transport and hooked in my own function that captured the item being destroyed first