kendo grid - how to get deleted records in a grid?
I am using kendo 2022 version and I want to know is there any handy function that gives the deleted records in a grid.
There was datasource.getDestroyed() function, but it seems it's not supported anymore in latest 2022 version..
Please let me know if any workarounds for this?

It's an old answer/workaround but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18389331/493557

In my case, I am not using transport config and loading data in some other way and so i can't depend on destroy method in it...
But finally I got this easy trick to solve this issue, so am posting here in case for anyone who got stuck.
You can use requestEnd event of datasource to achieve this easily.
requestEnd: function(e) {
            if (e.type == "destroy") {
                myArr.push(e.response.itemid);
            }
}

Hope this helps someone
